# linux + ssh login took time from one server to another

Tags: linux, ssh, login, authentication, sshd

I have a central Linux server (Red Hat version 6.5), and from this server I establish SSH sessions to other servers.

To one server the SSH login took around 5 seconds, while to all others
it took less than one second.

Can someone help me to understand the reasons for this problem?

Comment: Check the dns configuration of the your remote slow server.

Comment: What is your perceived login? Any particular banners/scripts to the slow server? I had one taking temperatures and stuff like that in  /etc/update-motd.d for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root cause of 98% similar problems is `UseDNS` parameter in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
Switch its value to `no` and try again

Comment: And restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you can resolve the name of this server with 'nslookup'
2. If not, switch off 'UseDNS' at /etc/ssh/sshd_config, or add your host to /etc/hosts

Should help.